# Clang AST Matchers: is it possible filter based on count?

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

I was trying to write a simple clang-tidy checker that will check for constructor that is calling `fopen()` more than once. For that I was tying to match the constructor with more than one `fopen()` calls. My indention is to find potential memory leak in case any exception happens in the second `fopen()` call.

```
class Dummy_File
{
  FILE *f1_, *f2_;

  public:
    Dummy_File(const char* f1, const char* f2, const char * mode)
    {
        f1_ = fopen(f1, mode);
        f2_ = fopen(f2, mode);
    }
};
```

Using this

```
match cxxConstructorDecl(hasDescendant(callExpr(callee(functionDecl(hasName("fopen")))))).bind("x")
```

I was able to find the constructor with `fopen`. But I wanted to find the constructor with more than one `fopen`. I was wondering if it is possible to filter based on count?

I checked logical narrowing matchers *(allOf, anyOf, anything and unless)* but did not find anything related to count.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no builtin matcher with required logic. However, it won't be hard to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ValeriySavchenko for the helpful direction. I am wondering, is there any examples that I can refer to?

Comment: I want to point out that every matcher that you listed checks exactly one node. Only traversal matchers like `has` and `hasDescendant` check many nodes, but they stop whenever they find the first match. I guess you would need some sort of a **counting** `hasDescendant`.
For this, you need to check how it is implemented. Also, recently I have answered another question including a custom matcher: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60448045/11582326 It has a somewhat similar idea of matching more than one child.